# X does not want to start. At all. "No screens have a usable configuration"

Tags: xorg, graphics, mac, lubuntu

I recently installed a fresh copy of lubuntu 11.04 powerpc on my computer.  I was following the instructions from this fourm post: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1798792
All I get is the command-line prompt.  I try to start X by running "startx" with no avail.

I googled for about 2 hours and there has been no success.

I have an Mac G4 800mhz 832mb ram 5400rpm 10gb and 37gb seagate internal HDD.

## Updated 2:52PM today

Here is the xorg.0.log:

```
[  1902.094] 
X.Org X Server 1.10.1
Release Date: 2011-04-15
[  1902.104] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[  1902.114] Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.35-23-powerpc64-smp ppc Ubuntu
[  1902.121] Current Operating System: Linux lubuntu 2.6.38-11-powerpc #48-Ubuntu Fri Jul 29 19:10:04 UTC 2011 ppc
[  1902.129] Kernel command line: root=UUID=940b9703-2dac-43fa-bf7e-973987bf28ee ro quiet splash 
[  1902.140] Build Date: 11 August 2011  03:47:04PM
[  1902.148] xorg-server 2:1.10.1-1ubuntu1.2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[  1902.156] Current version of pixman: 0.20.2
[  1902.165]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[  1902.173] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  1902.198] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Aug 25 14:50:16 2011
[  1902.212] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[  1902.223] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  1902.238] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[  1902.238] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen" (0)
[  1902.238] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Configured Monitor"
[  1902.240] (**) |   |-->Device "Configured Video Device"
[  1902.241] (==) Automatically adding devices
[  1902.241] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[  1902.241] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[  1902.241]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1902.241] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[  1902.241]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1902.241] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1" does not exist.
[  1902.242]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1902.242] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[  1902.242]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1902.242] (WW) The directory "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType" does not exist.
[  1902.242]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1902.242] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    built-ins
[  1902.242] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[  1902.242] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[  1902.242] (II) Loader magic: 0x101f3c20
[  1902.242] (II) Module ABI versions:
[  1902.242]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[  1902.243]    X.Org Video Driver: 10.0
[  1902.243]    X.Org XInput driver : 12.3
[  1902.243]    X.Org Server Extension : 5.0
[  1902.245] (--) PCI:*(0:0:16:0) 1002:5046:0000:0000 rev 0, Mem @ 0x94000000/67108864, 0x90000000/16384, I/O @ 0x00000400/256, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[  1902.246] (II) Open APM successful
[  1902.246] (II) LoadModule: "extmod"
[  1902.249] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libextmod.so
[  1902.250] (II) Module extmod: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1902.250]    compiled for 1.10.1, module version = 1.0.0
[  1902.250]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[  1902.250]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[  1902.250] (II) Loading extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[  1902.250] (II) Loading extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[  1902.250] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DGA
[  1902.250] (II) Loading extension DPMS
[  1902.250] (II) Loading extension XVideo
[  1902.250] (II) Loading extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[  1902.250] (II) Loading extension X-Resource
[  1902.251] (II) LoadModule: "dbe"
[  1902.252] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdbe.so
[  1902.253] (II) Module dbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1902.253]    compiled for 1.10.1, module version = 1.0.0
[  1902.253]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[  1902.253]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[  1902.253] (II) Loading extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[  1902.253] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  1902.254] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  1902.255] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1902.255]    compiled for 1.10.1, module version = 1.0.0
[  1902.256]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[  1902.256] (==) AIGLX enabled
[  1902.256] (II) Loading extension GLX
[  1902.256] (II) LoadModule: "record"
[  1902.259] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/librecord.so
[  1902.264] (II) Module record: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1902.265]    compiled for 1.10.1, module version = 1.13.0
[  1902.265]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[  1902.265]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[  1902.265] (II) Loading extension RECORD
[  1902.265] (II) LoadModule: "dri"
[  1902.266] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri.so
[  1902.267] (II) Module dri: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1902.267]    compiled for 1.10.1, module version = 1.0.0
[  1902.267]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[  1902.267] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DRI
[  1902.272] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[  1902.273] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
[  1902.274] (II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1902.274]    compiled for 1.10.1, module version = 1.2.0
[  1902.274]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[  1902.274] (II) Loading extension DRI2
[  1902.274] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
[  1902.280] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/ati_drv.so
[  1902.280] (II) Module ati: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1902.281]    compiled for 1.10.1, module version = 6.14.0
[  1902.281]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1902.281]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 10.0
[  1902.281] (II) LoadModule: "r128"
[  1902.283] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/r128_drv.so
[  1902.283] (II) Module r128: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1902.283]    compiled for 1.10.0, module version = 6.8.1
[  1902.283]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1902.283]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 10.0
[  1902.287] (II) R128: Driver for ATI Rage 128 chipsets:
    ATI Rage 128 Mobility M3 LE (PCI), ATI Rage 128 Mobility M3 LF (AGP),
    ATI Rage 128 Mobility M4 MF (AGP), ATI Rage 128 Mobility M4 ML (AGP),
    ATI Rage 128 Pro GL PA (PCI/AGP), ATI Rage 128 Pro GL PB (PCI/AGP),
    ATI Rage 128 Pro GL PC (PCI/AGP), ATI Rage 128 Pro GL PD (PCI),
    ATI Rage 128 Pro GL PE (PCI/AGP), ATI Rage 128 Pro GL PF (AGP),
    ATI Rage 128 Pro VR PG (PCI/AGP), ATI Rage 128 Pro VR PH (PCI/AGP),
    ATI Rage 128 Pro VR PI (PCI/AGP), ATI Rage 128 Pro VR PJ (PCI/AGP),
    ATI Rage 128 Pro VR PK (PCI/AGP), ATI Rage 128 Pro VR PL (PCI/AGP),
    ATI Rage 128 Pro VR PM (PCI/AGP), ATI Rage 128 Pro VR PN (PCI/AGP),
    ATI Rage 128 Pro VR PO (PCI/AGP), ATI Rage 128 Pro VR PP (PCI),
    ATI Rage 128 Pro VR PQ (PCI/AGP), ATI Rage 128 Pro VR PR (PCI),
    ATI Rage 128 Pro VR PS (PCI/AGP), ATI Rage 128 Pro VR PT (PCI/AGP),
    ATI Rage 128 Pro VR PU (PCI/AGP), ATI Rage 128 Pro VR PV (PCI/AGP),
    ATI Rage 128 Pro VR PW (PCI/AGP), ATI Rage 128 Pro VR PX (PCI/AGP),
    ATI Rage 128 GL RE (PCI), ATI Rage 128 GL RF (AGP),
    ATI Rage 128 RG (AGP), ATI Rage 128 VR RK (PCI),
    ATI Rage 128 VR RL (AGP), ATI Rage 128 4X SE (PCI/AGP),
    ATI Rage 128 4X SF (PCI/AGP), ATI Rage 128 4X SG (PCI/AGP),
    ATI Rage 128 4X SH (PCI/AGP), ATI Rage 128 4X SK (PCI/AGP),
    ATI Rage 128 4X SL (PCI/AGP), ATI Rage 128 4X SM (AGP),
    ATI Rage 128 4X SN (PCI/AGP), ATI Rage 128 Pro ULTRA TF (AGP),
    ATI Rage 128 Pro ULTRA TL (AGP), ATI Rage 128 Pro ULTRA TR (AGP),
    ATI Rage 128 Pro ULTRA TS (AGP?), ATI Rage 128 Pro ULTRA TT (AGP?),
    ATI Rage 128 Pro ULTRA TU (AGP?)
[  1902.294] (--) using VT number 7

[  1902.316] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/r128_drv.so
[  1902.317] (II) R128(0): PCI bus 0 card 16 func 0
[  1902.317] (==) R128(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[  1902.317] (II) R128(0): Pixel depth = 24 bits stored in 4 bytes (32 bpp pixmaps)
[  1902.317] (==) R128(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[  1902.317] (II) R128(0): VGAAccess option set to FALSE, VGA module load skipped
[  1902.317] (==) R128(0): RGB weight 888
[  1902.317] (II) R128(0): Using 8 bits per RGB (8 bit DAC)
[  1902.318] (**) R128(0): Using framebuffer device
[  1902.318] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[  1902.318] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[  1902.319] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[  1902.325] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1902.325]    compiled for 1.10.1, module version = 0.0.2
[  1902.326]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 10.0
[  1902.326] (EE) Unable to find a valid framebuffer device
[  1902.327] (EE) R128(0): Failed to open framebuffer device, consult warnings and/or errors above for possible reasons
    (you may have to look at the server log to see warnings)
[  1902.327] (II) UnloadModule: "r128"
[  1902.327] (II) Unloading r128
[  1902.327] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdevhw"
[  1902.327] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[  1902.327] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
[  1902.332] 
Fatal server error:
[  1902.332] no screens found
[  1902.332] 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[  1902.333] Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[  1902.333] 
[  1902.384]  ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
```

My Xorg.conf file:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Configured Video Device"
    Driver      "vesa"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
    Horizsync   24-82
    Vertrefresh 56-85
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    Monitor     "Configured Monitor"
    Device      "Configured Video Device"
    Subsection "Display"
       Modes    "800x600" "1024x768"
    EndSubsection
EndSection

Section "DRI"
  Mode 0666
EndSection
```

My monitor is a Sony Trinitron Multiscan 20se II.  I've been trying to install Linux for two week and I'm not giving up yet!  Almost, though

Comment: alexy13 - try adding `xforcevesa` to your grub boot string - this should give you a usable graphical desktop.

Comment: I never see the grub, how can I add it to the grub boot string?

Comment: ... oh yes - powerpc... its not grub its your yaboot.conf file as per the wiki https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ - n.b. look towards the bottom of the wiki-page. Alternatively (or perhaps better?) specify "vesa" instead of "ati" in your xorg.conf

Comment: alexy13 - your xorg.conf file looks very complicated - can you simplify it? - the forum link recommends "1 device section, 1 screen section, 1 monitor section "

Comment: I just updated my first post with new errors and a new Xorg.conf file

Comment: I booted in Linux single mode and I went to "failsafeXgraphics".  I saw a very simple GUI!  I tried to troubleshoot the problem, it did nothing.  I tried to boot ubuntu in "limited graphics mode" that didn't do anything either, it booted me back to the recovery mode screen :(

Comment: @fossfreedom let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1191/discussion-between-alexy13-and-fossfreedom)

Comment: Alexy13 - we didnt really finish this discussion yesterday - would you like to continue?

Comment: Do you got this working? Maybe this could help: http://lkubuntu.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/quick-and-easy-way-to-fix-x11-issues/

Comment: It didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm giving up.  Three weeks of troubleshooting, this is too much.  I decided to install Ubuntu on a virtual box on my iMac.  Then I deleted it because it was having issues with unity and after 2 days of trying to fix it, I gave up, again.  Thank you for all of the help that I received, because it did help.

Hi, Mac.  Long time no see.

Comment: Linux is not for the impatient. +1 for realizing that.

Answer (score 1):

## Second Try

[avtolle](http://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=111030) has [reported](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=772808) to make an iMac with with an ATI Rage 128 device (looks like yours) to work by adding this lines at the xorg file:

```
  
Section "Monitor"

Horizsync 28-51
Vertrefresh 43-60


Section "Screen"
SubSection "Display"
Modes "1024x768"
EndSubSection


Section "DRI"
Mode 0666
EndSection
```

Also you could change the `Modes "1024x768"` to yours (1152x870). *Be careful with this because setting a bigger resolution than your card support has been report to break the monitor.*

## First Try

Do you know the specs of your monitor?

Have a look at [this](http://www.x.org/wiki/FAQErrorMessages):

## "

Message: "Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration"

You get an error message:

```
(EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.  
Fatal server error:  
no screens found
```

In most cases this means there are no video modes available for your configuration. Each entry in the list of specified or default video modes gets checked if it lies withing the limit or the hardware: if it lies within the sync range specified or probed for the monitor, if it will work with the memory available on the video card or if the pixel clock lies within the range supported by the chipsets. There are many more limits. For each rejected mode you can see in the log file the reason for rejection:

```
...
(II) VGA(0): Not using default mode "320x200" (vrefresh out of range)  
(II) VGA(0): Not using default mode "720x400" (insufficient memory for mode)  
(II) VGA(0): Not using default mode "360x200" (hsync out of range)  
...
```

In most cases the monitor ranges are the reason why your modes where rejected. Please try to extend these ranges carefully until you get a working mode. Please note: on older monitors you need to be careful extending the ranges as it can be easily destroyed. There may be other reasons why you get this message.

If the specified depth is not supported with your hardware.

In this case try depth 8, or if you are using the vga driver even depth 4.
If you specified a combination of options the driver cannot handle.
If loading of a required sub module wasn't successful. In this case you'll get a message that the loading failed. Please try to investigate, why. The message may give you a clue: you may be using the wrong version of the module, or the file may not exist.

## "

Comment: The "default" one is 1152x870.  How would I be able to change that file?

Comment: Can you check if a file like `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` exists and post here? The usual locations of the configuration file are: /etc/X11/xorg.conf or /etc/X11/XF86Config-4.

Comment: I cannot post the file right now because I am occupied and will be for a long time :(.  It might be a while....  How would I post it if I'm in command-line only mode?  (Right now I'm using another computer)

Comment: You could just check if the 1152x870 was tested at the log file. I will have to leave, but I will come back soon.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: I have a different error now, I updated my question with the new log and conf file

Answer (score 1):

The error in your latest edit is due to a missing monitor section:

Can I suggest the following simple xorg.conf based on the values you have given:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Configured Video Device"
    Driver      "ATI Technologies Inc Rage 128 PF/PRO AGP 4x TMDS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
    Horizsync   24-82
    Vertrefresh 56-85
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    Monitor     "Configured Monitor"
    Device      "Configured Video Device"
    Subsection "Display"
       Modes    "800x600" "1024x768"
    EndSubsection
EndSection

Section "DRI"
  Mode 0666
EndSection
```

If you dont have the correct Driver "ATI Technologies Inc Rage 128 PF/PRO AGP 4x TMDS" value try "vesa" instead

Comment: Failed to load module "vesa" (module does not exist, 0).  I also tried "ati" and the "ATI Technologies..." driver as well.  I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

As I pointed out yesterday personally I feel the best solution for you would have been to post on the actual thread.  It is important that people let me know if they are having problems with the guide.  Maybe I have got something wrong or perhaps could explain it better?

You say you are using a non standard external monitor. Therefore it is inadvisable to use an xorg.conf that you just found 'on the internet'. If I am reading correctly you first tried to configure your own xorg.conf so that is good.  However, it is also useful to have a look at what other people do if you run into problems. Have a look on the linked site in the guide which has many sample xorg.conf files.

As previously advised you only need 1 of each section.  So shortening your orginal xorg.conf I get this:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen         "Screen0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "NoAccel"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SWcursor"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "Dac6Bit"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "Dac8Bit"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DMAForXv"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ForcePCIMode"          # [<bool>]
        #Option     "CCEPIOMode"            # [<bool>]
        #Option     "CCENoSecurity"         # [<bool>]
        #Option     "CCEusecTimeout"        # <i>
        #Option     "AGPMode"               # <i>
        #Option     "AGPSize"               # <i>
        #Option     "RingSize"              # <i>
        #Option     "BufferSize"            # <i>
        #Option     "EnablePageFlip"        # [<bool>]
        #Option     "Display"               # <str>
        #Option     "PanelWidth"            # <i>
        #Option     "PanelHeight"           # <i>
        #Option     "ProgramFPRegs"         # [<bool>]
        #Option     "UseFBDev"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "VideoKey"              # <i>
        #Option     "ShowCache"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "VGAAccess"             # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "r128"
    BusID       "PCI:0:16:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

If that doesn't work then try the following option in your device section:

Option      "UseFBDev"      "False"

Some people seem to use this too:

Option      "NoInt10"       "True"

For further queries please post on the thread/guide, but it seems you have given up so this answer maybe redundant anyway.  I hope you give lubuntu or xubuntu another try on your powerpc. The apple forum has a lot of information on it for you to tap into.

Answer (score 1):

Adding Option "NoInt10" "true", and setting "UseFBDev" to "false" works for certain, however you get a particularly sluggish system. The problem has to do with the fact that r128 support has been pulled from mesa-gl, and usually ubuntu pulls it from the distro as well. To solve this last problem I had to recompile a kernel with the rage 128 compiled as a built-in "driver". I now only have a problem with udev, which I currently workaround by stopping it with: sudo stop udev.

The following xorg.conf made my xserver work without recompiling a kernel, sluggish is better then nothing for now:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier      "ATI Technologies Inc Rage 128 PF/PRO AGP 4x TMDS"
    Driver          "r128"
    BusID           "PCI:0:16:0"
        Option      "UseFBDev"      "false"
        Option      "NoInt10"       "true"
        Option      "Display"       "CRT"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
    VendorName  "LG"
    ModelName   "LG FLATRON L1919S"
    HorizSync   30.0-83.0
    VertRefresh 56.0-75.0
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    Monitor     "Configured Monitor"
    Device      "ATI Technologies Inc Rage 128 PF/PRO AGP 4x TMDS"
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth       24
        Modes       "1280x1024" "1024x768" "800x600"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 1):

Colaborative wiki for Apple iMac G3 and others:

- http://wiki.gilug.org/index.php/AppleImacG3350-ubuntu1104

There you can find a working xorg.conf